# Forcing a soft keyboard to fill width of screen

Tags: android

I've created a simple pinnumber keyboard using this post as a basis for my program
http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

My problem arises with that the soft keyboard will not fill the entire width of my screen, even though I am using the %p dimensions.

Is there away to force my keyboard view so that it automaticly fills the width of the screen? Trying to use match/fill parents has not worked.

Comment: The link you have provided is broken..

Comment: http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Is there away to force my keyboard view so that it automaticly fills the width of the screen? Trying to use match/fill parents has not worked.>

Can you post your xml? Have you checked through it thoroughly to make sure that you are using match_parent in every location that relates to the width of the keyboard?

Comment: It definetly fits the screen, I made the %p tags to add up to over 100 and I still had the problem

Comment: android:keyWidth="33%p"
    android:keyHeight="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="4%p"
    android:verticalGap="1%p"

Comment: Can you post your full xml for the keyboard in your question. I cannot do anything with what you typed in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue.One solution is add two flexible spacers at left and right with the same background color as the keyboard.
The layout is something as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/btn_keyboard_key"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/black"
        android:keyTextSize="28dp"
        android:labelTextSize="20dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/grey"
        android:shadowRadius="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <View
        android:background="@color/"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```